# Js force auto focus prevent other link from working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im having a problem with my navbar in my price checker web base application.
my input field for barcode has an auto focus for my barcode scanner which prevented my navbar from working.

```
 $('#scanner').focus();
 $('#scanner').blur(function(){
     $('#scanner').focus();
 });
```

is there anyway to my other button to work while my input is in autofocus?

Comment: Could you please add the rest of your code?

Comment: Wouldn't calling `focus` on `blur` cause an infinite loop?

Comment: do you have a screenshot of what the page looks like or an image that indicates the issue? I am not sure if your problem is when you click on the link and the page is not redirecting or your scanner is not able to input anymore.

Comment: @JackBashford that is my only code for auto focus, and my navbar is from bootstrap. I change nothing in my bootstrap code. for barcode input i have device for barcode thats why i need to autofocus in my input so that every time my barcode scan it displays in my input

Comment: @George where should i put my focus()? if not in blur?

Comment: @IanP. there is no problem in my input, my only problem is my navbar or other buttons, it did not work anymore because of my force auto focus on my inpiut

Comment: @4techtestlast If you put it in the blur, you'll never unfocus the input as everytime you unfocus it, it will focus it right back, causing a loop you'll never get out of. Without seeing any other code, it's anyone's guess at what else if anything is the issue.

Comment: can you paste your html code as well? or just the part where it shows the navbar and the scanner input field, how are you so sure that the issue is with the autofocus? do the navbar buttons work when you remove the autofocus code?

Comment: @George - Is right.  The way you have this written you will never be able to click on anything besides your input.  Since we don't know your intended functionality it would be hard to tell you what you need to do.

Comment: @4techtestlast you can use `autofocus` in HTML

Comment: @George yes i understand what you are trying to say. but is there a way to still work my autofocus on my input for my barcode scanner while my other will buttons still work?

Comment: @4techtestlast  Only call `focus()` once and don't put it in the blur handler, as I said before it's near impossible to help with only this snippet of code as anything else on your page could also be calling `focus()`

Comment: thanks everyone. i fix it from adding setTimeout in my on.blur function.